# MATLAB Rounding only the finally returned value of a recursive function

Tags: matlab, recursion

I am trying to create a recursive FFT function which rounds its output to 1 decimal place, without rounding all the recursion outputs.

My code produces the correct unrounded output when I do not implement rounding. However, when I implement rounding, it rounds each recursion, which causes the final output to be off by some amount.

How do you go about only rounding the final output? Below is my current code, with rounding implemented at the 2nd to last line.

```
function X = hw41(x);
M = length(x);
X = zeros(1,M);
k_1 = 0:(M/2 - 1);
k_2 = M/2:(M - 1);
x_even = x(1:2:M);
x_odd = x(2:2:M);
e_1 = exp((-2*pi*j/M) * k_1);
e_2 = exp((-2*pi*j/M) * k_2);

    if M/2 < 1
        X = x;
    else
        X(1:M/2) = hw41(x_even(1:M/2)) + (e_1 .* hw41(x_odd(1:M/2)));
        X((M/2 + 1):M) = hw41(x_even(1:M/2)) + (e_2 .* hw41(x_odd(1:M/2)));
    end

X = round(X, 1);
end
```

Comment: Have you considered to use a wrapper which calls your functions and then rounds the final result?